# Completeness of a normed space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, cv.complex-variables, differential-equations, integration

We consider the set $\mathcal{PC}([-r,0],X)$

$$\mathcal{PC}([-r,0],X):=\{\varphi:[-r, 0] \rightarrow X: \varphi \text{ is continuous everywhere except
    for a finite number 
of points  } t_* \text{ such that } \varphi\left(t_*^{-}\right) \text{ and }
\varphi\left(t_*^{+}\right) \text{ exist  and } \varphi\left(t_*\right)=\varphi\left(t_*^{-}\right) \}$$

equipped with the following norm $$\|\varphi\|=\displaystyle\int_{-r}^{0}\|\varphi(\theta)\|d\theta. $$
We consider a space $\mathcal{B}_{g}$ as
$$
\mathcal{B}_{g}:=\left\{\varphi:(-\infty, 0] \rightarrow X:\left.\varphi\right|_{[-r, 0]} \in \mathcal{PC}([-r,0],X) \text {  and } \int_{-\infty}^0 g(\theta)\|\varphi(\theta)\| d \theta<+\infty\right\}.
$$
Then, we set
$$
\|\varphi\|_{\mathcal{B}_{g}}=\int_{-\infty}^0 g(\theta)\|\varphi(\theta)\| d \theta, \text { for all } \varphi \in \mathcal{B}_{g}.
$$
where $g:(-\infty,0]\longrightarrow (0,+\infty)$ is a continuous function such that $\rho=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{0}g(s)ds<+\infty.$ I made every effort to demonstrate the completeness of the space $\mathcal{B}_{g}$. However, I encountered a significant challenge when attempting to prove that the restriction of the limit of the Cauchy sequence, taken in $\mathcal{B}_{g}$, onto the interval $[-r,0]$, belongs to $\mathcal{PC}([-r,0],X)$. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance, please.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that $\mathcal{B}_g$ is complete. The inverse of the Cantor function (take a caglad version) can be expressed as the uniform limit of caglad functions , each of which with finitely many discontinuities. Under you hypotheses, uniform convergence implies $\mathcal{B}_g$ convergence, but the inverse Cantor function is not in $\mathcal{B}_g$ as you defined it, as it has infinitely many discontinuity points.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please provide more explicit details or clarification?

Comment: Of course this space  can't be complete . Think of $X=\mathbb R$, $g:=e^\theta$ (if you want an example with $\rho<\infty$, or just $g:=1$ to make it simpler). Then $B_g$ is dense in $L^1$, where you can find functions that are everywhere discontinuous and unbounded.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help.